# CLLocationManager delegate not called from Siri Intents

Tags: core-location, cllocationmanager, ios13, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I'm trying to use the CLLocationManager to find a user's current location from within a Siri Intent in iOS13. In the intent's `handle` method, I am setting up the CLLocationManager to make the call, but the delegate calls to `didUpdateLocations` or `didFailWithError` don't end up being called at all.

```
- (void)handleMyIntent:(MyIntent *)intent completion:(void (^)(MyIntentResponse *response))completion {
// the handle method is called on an arbitrary queue, so I’m dispatching to main_queue

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
   });
}
```

The breakpoints to the handler does get hit (after dispatch to main queue), and I have added a usage string in Info.plist. I got an initial warning was against using the CLLocationManager on an arbitrary queue, hence I dispatch it to the main queue.

Any idea why the delegate methods aren't getting hit?

Comment: Likewise I'm only able to use CBCentralManager delegate methods once and only

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?